# Why does calling a function modify the value of an array of pointer to function that weren't given in parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gdb

I've got a struct that contains a pointer to function and an array of pointers to function. I'm passing the first pointer (not the array) as parameter of a function which is supposed to tell me whether an array of integers is sorted or not (it can be in ascending or descending order and this is defined by compFct, which is the pointer to function given in parameter).

Unfortunately that function is changing the values in the array of pointers in my struct (without changing the value of my pointer to function given in parameter).

Using gdb I managed to know when were made the changes in my array. It appears to be modified after the first printf in the printSorted function.

My typedef :

```c
typedef int (*PtrCompFct)(int, int);
typedef int (*PtrSortFct)(int*, int, int, PtrCompFct);
```

The struct :

```c
typedef struct
{
    int nbFct;
    PtrCompFct compFct;
    PtrSortFct *sortFct;
} SortCompFct_s;
```

Here is how I'm calling my function (userChoices is of SortCompFct_s type):

```c
printSorted(myArr, myArrSize, userChoices->compFct);
```

And the fonction that is changing my structure :

```c
int printSorted(int *arr, int arrSize, PtrCompFct compFct)
{
    for (int i=0; i<(arrSize-1); i++)
    {
        if (compFct(arr[i+1], arr[i]))
        {
            //this is when my array of pointers to function is modified
            printf("The array isn't sorted\n\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("The array is sorted\n\n");
    return 1;
}
```

With gdb before the printf I have :

```c
(gdb) print main::userChoices->sortFct[0]
$36 = (PtrSortFct) 0x5555555548ea <quickSort>
```

and after :

```c
(gdb) print main::userChoices->sortFct[0]
$37 = (PtrSortFct) 0x7fffffffddc0
```

As you can see the pointer to my quickSort function has been modified.

EDIT : include of the simplified and verifiable code, the thing is that this code is working properly, even with the printSorted function

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef int (*PtrCompFct)(int, int);
typedef int (*PtrSortFct)(int*, int, int, PtrCompFct);

typedef struct
{
    int nbFct;
    PtrCompFct compFct;
    PtrSortFct *sortFct;
} SortCompFct_s;

typedef SortCompFct_s *PtrSortCompFct_s;

void initTab(int *arr, int arrSize)
{
    time_t t;
    srand(time(&t));
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
}

int ascendingSort(int elmt1, int elmt2)
{
    return (elmt1 < elmt2);
}

int descendingSort(int elmt1, int elmt2)
{
    return (elmt1 > elmt2);
}

void switche(int *arr, int ind1, int ind2)
{
    int temp = arr[ind1];
    arr[ind1] = arr[ind2];
    arr[ind2] = temp;
}

int bubbleSort(int *arr, int ind1, int ind2, PtrCompFct fctComp)
{
    int sorted;
    for (int i=ind1; i<ind2; i++)
    {
        sorted = 1;

        for (int j=0; j<ind2; j++)
        {
            if (fctComp(arr[j+1], arr[j]))
            {
                switche(arr, j, j+1);
                sorted = 0;
            }
        }

        if (sorted) return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

void printArr(int *arr, int arrSize)
{
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize; i++)
    {
        printf("%16d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}

int printSorted(int *arr, int arrSize, PtrCompFct compFct)
{
    for (int i=0; i<arrSize-1; i++)
    {
        if (compFct(arr[i+1], arr[i]))
        {
            //this is when my array of pointers to function is modified
            printf("The array isn't sorted\n\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("The array is sorted\n\n");
    return 1;
}

PtrSortCompFct_s menu(void)
{
    PtrSortCompFct_s userChoices;
    PtrSortFct arrSortFct[] = {bubbleSort};

    if ((userChoices = malloc(3*sizeof(int))) != NULL)
    {
        userChoices->nbFct = 1;
        userChoices->compFct = ascendingSort;
        userChoices->sortFct = arrSortFct;
    }

    return userChoices;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arrSize = 10;
    int arr[arrSize];
    initTab(arr, arrSize);
    PtrSortCompFct_s userChoices;

    if ((userChoices = malloc(3*sizeof(int))) != NULL) userChoices = menu();

    printArr(arr, arrSize);
    printSorted(arr, arrSize, userChoices->compFct);

    userChoices->sortFct[0](arr, 0, arrSize-1, userChoices->compFct);

    printArr(arr, arrSize);
    printSorted(arr, arrSize, userChoices->compFct);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Why `-1` in `for (int i=0; i<(arrSize-1); i++)`?  IAC, you need to post the call to `printSorted()` as part of an [mcve].  I suspect your sort function is amiss.

Comment: Where/how does `main::userChoices->sortFct` get its value?

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't that be -2 to avoid reading outside the bounds of the array?

Comment: @chux the -1 is because my parameter is the number of elements in the array and not the last index. My sort function is working, I tried setting the value of `userChoices->sortFct[0]` to `0x5555555548ea` with gdb after it has been modified and the rest of my program worked perfectly fine.

Comment: 1) Rather than use _gdb_, print the function pointer values out before and after.  Recommend `printf("llx\n", (unsigned long long) userChoices->sortFct[i]);`  2) With "my parameter is the number of elements in the array", code should _not_ use `-1`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm from there `if ((userChoices = malloc(6*sizeof(int))) != NULL) userChoices = menu()` where menu is a function that returns a SortCompFct_s structure

Comment: `userChoices = malloc(6*sizeof(int))` is the wrong size allocation.

Comment: You're leaking memory with that.  What is `menu` doing to create the data to return?

Comment: Without a [mcve], this post is insufficient for a good answer.

Comment: @chux for the 2) sorry I told you something wrong that's the last index and not the number of elements, hence the -1

Comment: If `arrSize` is the " last index and not the number of elements", then code shroud use `+1`: `for (int i=0; i<(arrSize+1); i++)` or `<=` and `for (int i=0; i<=arrSize; i++)`

Comment: @chux I understand (by the way how should I initialize such a structure ?) but that shouldn't cause any problem there if it didn't caused any when affecting the return of menu to my variable right ?

Comment: @chux, 1201ProgramAlarm I'll try to make it more understandable tomorrow morning !

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the first line of the for loop. Type `watch main::userChoices->sortFct[0]` then `cont`. It will stop when your program modifies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With gdb before the printf I have: ... and after:

The root cause of your problem is in how you have initialized `userChoices->sortFct` (you have not shown the code which performs this initialization).

That array is pointing to *dangling* heap or stack memory, and a call to `printf` overwrites that memory.

> `if ((userChoices = malloc(6*sizeof(int))) != NULL) userChoices = menu();`

That code is completely bogus: heap-allocating memory for `userChoices` and then immediately overwriting `userChoices` with return value from `menu()` only serves to leak memory. As mentioned in the comments, `6*sizeof(int)` is also completely bogus size.

I would guess that your `menu()` looks something like this:

```
struct SortCompFct_s* menu()
{
   struct SortCompFct_s ret;
   ret.compFct = &SomeFunc;
   ret.sortFct = malloc(...);
   ret.sortFct[0] = &quickSort;
   return &ret;    // Oops: returning address of a local!
}
```

If that is in fact what you did, dangling stack is exactly your problem. You should turn on maximum compiler warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` if using GCC), so the compiler tells you you are doing something wrong.

**Update:**

My guess was close:

```
PtrSortCompFct_s menu(void)
{
    PtrSortCompFct_s userChoices;
    PtrSortFct arrSortFct[] = {bubbleSort};

    if ((userChoices = malloc(3*sizeof(int))) != NULL)
    {
        userChoices->nbFct = 1;
        userChoices->compFct = ascendingSort;
        userChoices->sortFct = arrSortFct;
    }

    return userChoices;
}
```

The problem is that `userChoices->sortFct` points to a local (stack) variable `arrSortFct`. That local variable becomes invalid after return from `menu`, and at that point `userChoices->sortFct` is pointing to dangling stack (as I guessed).

Here is correct way to write this function (omitting error checking of `malloc` return for clarity):

```
PtrSortCompFct_s menu(void)
{
    PtrSortCompFct_s userChoices;
    PtrSortFct arrSortFct[] = {bubbleSort};

    if ((userChoices = malloc(sizeof(*userChoices)) != NULL)
    {
        userChoices->nbFct = 1;
        userChoices->compFct = ascendingSort;
        userChoices->sortFct = malloc(sizeof(arrSortFct));
        memcpy(userChoices->sortFct, arrSortFct, sizeof(arrSortFct));
    }

    return userChoices;
}
```

You should also need to fix your `main` like so:

PtrSortCompFct_s userChoices;

```
PtrSortCompFct_s userChoices = menu();
... use userChoices ...

free(userChoices->sortFct);
free(sortFct);
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm wondering how should I initialize such a structure ? And what about the code I added to my post ? Based on what you said it should end in a seg fault like the previous one, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly fine thanks. The `malloc(sizeof(arrSortFct)` is used to   create a non local variable that won't get later overwrited by a printf right ?

Comment: @FloXire `malloc` allocates space on heap. That space (unlike stack) does not become invalid when a function returns. It only becomes invalid once you explicitly call `free` on it.